# How to setup cronjob for pacsoft magento extension

Tags: magento, cron

I am working on a magento site where i installed Post Danmark - Pacsoft Online - 1.6.1
Everything is working fine but cronjob for Track & Trace is not work. Anyone can help me, I am really stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the settings of your cronjob?

Answer (score 0):

Just set up cron.php on Magento installation root i.e same directory as your bootstrap index.php file, your server, if you are unaware of that let me know will give you details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have checked cron.php is already there.